# How to set BinaryField to primary key in django?

Tags: django, binary

In this code i have:

```
IDChuyenBien = models.BinaryField(primary_key=True, max_length=8)
```

But when i makemigrations and migrate have an error:

```
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1170, "BLOB/TEXT column 'IDChuyenBien' used in key specification without a key length")
```

Although I used `max_length` as above, I am using `Django 4.2.9` connect to `Mysql`.

I followed the docs as follows:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/

I have also tried to think of a few other ways but still do not have a solution, because it is required that the data transmitted is binary and will be saved directly to the database, and before that when I did not use the `primary key`, in mysql when migrating it was also LONGBLOB. Meanwhile t only needs BINARY type with 8 bytes or 10 bytes

Comment: Django does not take the length of the field to the SQL database. Why exactly do you want to make this the primary key?

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**: at the moment of writing, you can not set a `BinaryField` as a primary key.

Django does not take the length of the field to the SQL database, it is only used to validate items *internally*. This thus means that for MySQL, it will use a `longblob`, for Oracle a `BLOB`, for PostgreSQL a `bytea` and for SQLite a `BLOB`. Indeed, [as we see for example for MySQL <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/7646b9023da7e1f6f3a871959db027b3ea36eebb/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py#L111-L113):

> ```
> "BinaryField": "longblob",
> "BooleanField": "bool",
> "CharField": "varchar(%(max_length)s)",
> ```

So in this case, a `BinaryField` translates to a `longblob` in MySQL, whereas for a `CharField`, it picks `varchar(…)`, but *specifies* the length.

This is thus *not* passed to the database backend, and therefore you can not use the field as a primary key, since only for small blobs, it does the effort of hashing.

That being said, it is probably *not* a good idea to use a `BinaryField` in the first place. In fact, in Django an using an `AutoField` is the norm, and one can then use for example [**`GenericForeignKey`** fields <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey) that exploits the fact that primary keys are *uniform*.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against using a `BinaryField` as the primary key at first place.
I will recommend based on best practice for selecting primary keys for your table:

1. A primary key must be unique and maintain this constraint consistently over time.
2. It's recommended that if possible the primary key must not directly inputted by the user. This helps ensure consistency and integrity.
3. Using an auto-incrementing primary key is mostly preferable as it offers more flexibility and has less time complexity on operations.

If you want to use `BinaryField`, there's a higher chance of encountering duplicates, which could have impact on the uniqueness.

Also, storing binary data consumes more database space and requires more time and resources for operations, especially when dealing with large amount of data.

Comment: Was this written by a chatbot (*ChatGPT*, *Google Gemini*, etc.)?

Comment: No, i write based on my daily experience with databases like Postgress and Oracles

Comment: Strange thing is that both zerogpt.com and gptzero.me flag this as AI-generated.

Comment: Given you can make a blob primary key, doesn't that automatically imply that the database will add a uniqness constraint? I don't really understand the "which could have impact on the uniqness"? The database does guarantee that.

Comment: It will make uniqness constraint, but database will not create these blob/binary data, you will need to create them and save to the database. So, here is the challenge, if you create blob which at some point have similar to the existing in your database, it will give you errors "UNIQUE CONSTRAINT VIOLATED"